# Remove columns / headers / grid from email view in Outlook

Tags: microsoft-outlook

Somehow my outlook view changed to use a grid format like this

[image: outlook grid view]

And I can't figure out how to change it back to be the simpler view like this:

[image: outlook condensed view]

Answer (score 19, accepted):

1. Go to the **View Ribbon**
2. Click on **View Settings**

   [image: View Settings]
3. Click on **Other Settings**

   [image: Other Settings]
4. Select **Always use compact layout**

   [image: Always use compact layout]

Comment: Accurate answer, thanks for your sharing.

Comment: Only answer that worked for me, others simply told me to reset the view but that didn't do anything.